Using ASP.NET Core 8 MVC with jquery-ajax-unobtrusive but what's the best way to handle unexpected exceptions?
I am using jquery-ajax-unobtrusive to make an ajax call to the controller endpoint in an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app.
The endpoint returns a PartialView if successful and is working as expected on success 200.
However, where I am struggling with is best practice on how to deal with an unexpected exception. E.g. the database times out during save.
I could hook into the data-ajax-failure="onFailure" and spit out the exception response info into an alert or div...
But in my mind, as it is likely in the future the project will configure custom error pages to deal with different types of exceptions and style those pages as preferred...
I don't want to circumvent this just because I happen to be doing a partial view ajax post.
In other words I think the best thing would be for the whole page to display the intended error page.  But I don't know how best to handle this?
I did try to achieve this by writing the jqXHR to the document...
if (jqXHR.status !== 200) {
     // Replace the entire body content with the server response
     alert('replace error');
     document.open();
     document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
     document.close();
}

But the jqXHR.responseText appears to only be the exception details and not the html to render the error page (See Actual vs Expected).
Actual:

Expected:

I guess then that when doing a standard full page postback, somewhere along the pipeline a redirect is returned which is not being handled during the ajax call.
This makes me believe I am approaching this incorrectly, either in the controller endpoint or javascript?
UPDATE:
Whilst I did not solve the reason why the screen shown in Expected: above (exception handling page) was not displaying properly...
After it occurred to me that this exception page is for development / debugging purposes only...  I configured a 'production' ready error page.  Once I did this using the page was being displayed fully as expected.
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


There are a lot of different ways you could go about this. If you're starting a new project, I would recommend considering a more modern front-end stack like React, Svelte, or Angular. These stacks separate concerns better than the MVC/jQuery pattern does, which will make handling error cases a lot more straightforward: errors can just be returned as part of the JSON response, and the UI code running on the front end can determine how the error should be rendered.
But in case that's not an option, I will share a pattern I ended up adopting on a past application using MVC/jQuery and utilizing unobtrusive javascript patterns.
I wrote the application so all of the AJAX endpoints were expected to return a JSON payload containing an array of events, and every AJAX-enabled action would simply emit all of the events that came back. Each event would have a "type" and a payload, and over time I found the events became more like commands, with one UI handler associated with each event type.
In the normal execution path, a single event would be returned, whose "type" was something like "ReplaceContent"--meant to replace a specified part of the UI with some HTML that usually came from rendering a partial view. Whenever HTML was replaced in this way, the UI code would scan the updated HTML with jQuery to apply any necessary handlers or modifications based on unobtrusive javascript patterns. In cases where more than one part of the UI might need updating, the server could return multiple events. This event-based approach was flexible enough to allow for advanced interactions like opening and closing modal dialog boxes, etc.
When an error occurred, the server-side error handlers would return an event that knew how to represent the error to the user. That could mean showing the event details in a dialog box or a "toast" for example. In dev environments, we might include details like the Exception message and stack trace, while in prod environments we might just say "something unexpected happened, and we couldn't complete this action; if this keeps happening, reach out to a representative for help." Most users don't care that your database query timed out, because there's nothing they can do about it.
I can't say what the "best" way would be to build your application, but I found this architecture allowed me to reuse UI code and components very effectively, and with enough flexibility to elegantly handle very complex interactions, including error cases.

Thanks, unfortunately as the project isn't new I do need to stick with MVC.  In the end I have returned JSON payloads in some of the AJAX endpoints. I suspect you are correct that the level of client side behaviour required probably points towards a different Non-MVC tech choice.  Sadly, as I say, this is not an option.
